# Can't retrieve zero values when using COUNT and GROUP together

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with a MYSQL query, when using COUNT and GROUP together it's excluding any rows that have a count of 0. I understand why this is happening but can't work out how to get around it. I've read up on potential solutions presented to those with a similar problem but I cannot see the link between the two that would allow me to solve it.

Can anybody help?

```
$query = "SELECT id, class_date, class_id, COUNT(*) AS reserve_count  
      FROM bookings
      WHERE booking_status='#RESERVE#'
      GROUP BY class_date, class_id
      ORDER BY class_date ASC, class_id ASC" ;

$result = mysqli_query($sql,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $bookings[$row['id']] = array('class_date' => $row['class_date'], 'class_id' => $row['class_id'], 'reserve_count' => $row['reserve_count']);
}
```

Comment: You can solve this with a `JOIN`

Comment: That's interesting, I saw that suggested in another post I read, I can't get my head around how it would help though.

Comment: I can't be sure, so I'll not make it an answer, but try somthing like: `SELECT id, IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS total FROM my_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id GROUP BY t1.id`

Comment: Couldn't you select class_date, class_id rows, that don't have a booking_status of '#RESERVE' and add the with UNION to the result?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, there shouldn't be any row with zero count because booking table should only have classes that are booked.